import uinput fails (Debian, Python3, Anaconda)
I've been trying to get a program to work that adds compatibility for G-Keys on the Logitech G910 keyboard. This failed though, and after some digging, I discovered that one of it's dependencies, the python module uinput, seems to crash the program.
Python 3.11.7 (main, Dec 15 2023, 18:12:31) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uinput
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/usr/anaconda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uinput/__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
    _libsuinput_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "_libsuinput" + sysconfig.get_config_var("SO")))
                                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str


At this point, I am kinda baffled. I've  never seen an import command fail before. The only thing I can imagine is that Anaconda is causing  issues here? If  anyone has  some insight  to  share, I would be delighted.
I am currently running this Debian 12 (Kernel Version 5.18.0-3-amd64), Python Version  3.11.7,  Conda Version 24.3.0, and uinput version 0.11.2 (installed via pip install python-uinput).
Any help is much appreciated!

You have an old version of uinput that uses code that was removed in python 3.5 and has since been removed from python-uinput, see this commit. So it might help to upgrade to a newer version.
pip install python-uinput==1.0.1


Thank you that worked. For some reason, the G-Keys compatibility required the uinput version of 0.11.2 and always installed that one because of it. Lets hope the  program runs on the newer version regardless, or I will have to look into setting up a python environment with downgraded python.

You could also try downloading the source of version 0.11.2 and manually patch the source code to remove the line that doesn't work
